# Protect Direct Line Secret in Botframework for Web Client

Tags: node.js, oauth, botframework, access-token, direct-line-botframework

I have my bot ready and working with Direct Line Secret in WebChat *(by passing &s=SECRET in URL)* and on other channels.

I am interested in the integration of front-end Custom Chat Application using Direct Line ClientJS *(link at bottom)*.

After going through the documentation on Bot Framework I came to know that it can be done in 2 ways:

1. Pass Direct Line secret from front-end Chat Application in ClientJS
2. Passing Token from front-end Chat Application **(But, this requires Direct Line Secret to be passed to generate token first time)**

> As I develop bots for my clients with their respective use-cases which
> need to be kept private with client servers.

So, anybody having Direct Line Secret can easily obtain Bots Logic *(i.e Not actual code, but what answer bot replies to particular question)* by just passing that Direct Line secret in Microsoft Bot Framework provided WebChat client *(by passing s=SECRET in URL)*

#### So, basically, how do I hide the secret from others?

Direct Line Client : https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/core-DirectLine

Authentication Mechanism : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-authentication

Programming Languages:

- FrontEnd - Angular.js with Typescript
- Backend - Node.js on Heroku

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow method #2 as described in the section [Generate a Direct Line Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-authentication#generate-token). Then you won't have to use the secret in your WebChat page at all.

> A Direct Line token is a key that can be used to access a single conversation. A token expires but can be refreshed.

This way your client will use the generated token on a per-conversation basis, and there's no need to embed the secret in the WebChat page. Also when you are using the token it will expire, so you have additional security there as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
If you check the code details for method #2, For generating First Token you need to pass **SECRET** in Bearer property, which again **Defeats purpose of hiding secret**

Comment: Method #2 can be done from server-side and your secret will be hidden from client side

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you you need put the secret altogether for direct line but there are ways you can handle in you bot code to avoid using to other people.

Follow the below steps:

```
1) you can pass the domain where you want to implement with user login context.
2) login context will go in bot code and will be check server side that the user which is logged in having authorized to access or to use your chat bot.
3) Restrict your bot to that particular domain.
4) Check authentication in bot using sign in feature via card.
```

I hope above liners will help you.
do let me know in case you need more help.

Comment: Thanks, Domain is also provided in front-end requests with DirectLine Connection object. So anyone can take domain and secret and pass it to Microsoft Sample Codes where we can pass arguments in URL as **&s=<SECRET>&domain=<DOMAIN>** which will again **start serving attackers the actual Bot replies**

Comment: you have to use combinations not only domain. login context will go in bot code and will be check server side that the user which is logged in having authorized to access or to use your chat bot.

Comment: I agree with it Manoj, But this solution will not work if I am developing public bots (i.e. without user authentication). **So can you help me how to handle that kind of issue?**

NOTE: Still in public bots its not great to have bots questions/answers exposed just by knowing DirectLine Secret and Domain information.

Eg. I have one bots details and since it didn't have user authentication as the business case to integrate with it. So, I am able to use that bot without any code just by using secret in Microsoft WebChat demo.

Comment: Can anybody help?